# Amazon scraper no data display

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scripting

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep 

headers = ({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

search_query = 'home office'.replace(' ', '+')

base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={0}'.format(search_query)

items = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    print('Processing {0}...'.format(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i)))
    response = requests.get(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-result-item', 'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
```

I don't know why each time to run the code. it only appends the strings together and gives me the link to the pages. It doesn't scrape any data from the page at all. I attached a screen shot of my screen as well[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGJfn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is you never append / return / print your `ResultSet`

```
...
for i in range(1, 11):
    print('Processing {0}...'.format(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i)))
    response = requests.get(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items.extend(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-result-item', 'data-component-type': 's-search-result'}))
print(items)
```

###### Example

This will iterate the `ResultSet`and store each item as dict with specific information in your list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep 

headers = ({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

search_query = 'home office'.replace(' ', '+')

base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={0}'.format(search_query)

items = []

for i in range(1, 2):
    print('Processing {0}...'.format(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i)))
    response = requests.get(base_url + '&page={0}'.format(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-result-item', 'data-component-type': 's-search-result'}):
        items.append({
            'title':item.h2.text,
            'url': item.a.get('href')
        })

items
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Raven Pro Document Scanner - Huge Touchscreen, High Speed Color Duplex Feeder (ADF), Wireless Scan to Cloud, WiFi, Ethernet, USB, Home or Office Desktop  ',
  'url': '/sspa/click?ie=UTF8&spc=MTo4NzYzMDkwMjIzMjg0MTI3OjE2NjAzOTk5ODA6c3BfYXRmOjIwMDAyMzU4Mzg0OTg2MTo6MDo6&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&url=%2FRaven-Pro-Document-Scanner-Touchscreen%2Fdp%2FB07MFRJWY6%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dhome%2Boffice%26qid%3D1660399980%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1'},
 {'title': 'Home Office Desk Chair, Ergonomic Mesh Executive Office Chair with 3 Position Tilt Function, Comfortable High Back Black Computer Chair with 3D Adjustable Armrest & Lumbar Support, FANMEN  ',
  'url': '/Ergonomic-Executive-Comfortable-Adjustable-FANMEN/dp/B09KRKX9FT/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=home+office&qid=1660399980&sr=8-2'},
 {'title': 'bonsaii Paper Shredder for Home Use,6-Sheet Crosscut Paper and Credit Card Shredder for Home Office,Home Shredder with Handle for Document,Mail,Staple,Clip-3.4 Gal Wastebasket(C237-B)  ',
  'url': '/bonsaii-Paper-Shredder-6-Sheet-Crosscut-Paper-Design-Home-Shredder-Clip-3-4-Gal-Wastebasket-C237-B/dp/B0834J2SVR/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=home+office&qid=1660399980&sr=8-3'},...]
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt print the result like yours do it print all the elements on the page and the title and url as well

Comment: So it works, that sounds great. The output in my answers is related exactly to my example, it seems that you mix both. To fix you have to decide if you need all the elements raw or only specific information.

Comment: Oh yeah it does!!! finally!!! I have been on this for hours, Thanks a lot